# How to access a ninject dependency in an HtmlHelper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject, html-helper

My MVC app has DI handled by Ninject
I would like to write an HtmlHelper which can consume a dependency maintained by Ninject.

I have a Custom resource manager for Translations, I would like to use a HtmlHelper to write down the translated strings to Javascript variables.

Comment: Since helpers are static you have no option of constructor injection. I'm sure there are some workarounds such as using a service locator (an anti-pattern) but I question why you would want do do this - it goes against MVC's separation of concerns. Why not just get the data in the controller, then pass the data to the helper as a parameter - much the same as you pass a `SelectList` to the `DropDownistFor()` helper

Comment: @StephenMuecke: This for the "Please wait message" during ajax calls so, I would end up providing this info in every controller. Didn't wanted to repeat, so thought of getting an HtmlHelper, which can be called in _Layout.cshtml and provided to JS framework, from there on!

Comment: I think there are better ways to go. For example a custom ActionFilter that you could apply globally or just to specific methods. You can inject into its constructor, and set a ViewBag property for instance that could be read in the _Layout